# Ajax call. Passing value to another php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem and hope you can help.
Ii have a status.PHP file containing a js.

**STATUS.PHP**

```
<? ..stuff... ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BCM Status Page</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="updater.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#305c57" onload='init();'>
```

As you can see in the html ihave included a JS, during "onload" i'm calling the init() function of the javascript called updater.js

Now in the **UPDATER.JS**

```
function init() {
    setInterval(read, 2000)
}

function read() {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'readDB.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(json_obj[0].gwnumber);   
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error loading data");
        }
    });

}
```

I'm doing an ajax call to the readDB.php that is working as intended, infact i have the correct value in the json_obj.

My question is: how can i get the json_obj value and pass it to the status.PHP file that is the one who's including the JS too?
Hope you can help. TY

Comment: Something is very wrong if you have `type: 'POST'` **and** `dataType: 'jsonp'` — JSONP only does GET requests.

Comment: Something is very wrong if you have `$.parseJSON(data);` — The `dataType` should tell jQuery how to parse the response.

Comment: In order to do what you ask first fix your AJAX as @Quentin tells you and then send the value back to status.php with another AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is a lot to say in this argument, but i will be the briefiest possible.

**first things first**

php and Javascript are two different programming language with a completely different paradigm.
The first is a [back-end focused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends#Back-end_focused) programming language;

Javascript instead is more [front-end focused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends#Front-end_focused), just for entirety i have to mention that JS is used also for the backend part with a special eviroment called [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)

back to the problem, the things that you are trying to do is not impossible but is excactly as you asked, your're idea (if i got it) was to pass the data from the js to the php like a parameter in a function...

the thing is that the php is elaborate and renderizated before in the server and the javascript is executed in the client, in the client web page there is no more footprint the php. This process is described very well at this link: http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

The possible solution is:

FRONT-END(js): make another ajax call(request) to the same page that you are displaying with all the data that you want to elaborate.

BACK-END(php): controll if this request has been made, then access the data with the global variables `$_POST & $_GET` (depending on the type of the request), then elaborate this data.

if I can I suggest you to make a check if the manipulation that you want to do on those data need to be done in the server-side and not by the js!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the order of execution:

1. User visits status.php
2. Browser requests status.php
3. Server executes status.php and sends response to browser
4. JS requests readDB.php
5. Browser requests readDB.php
6. Server executes readDB.php and sends response to browser
7. JS processes response
8. Go To 4

By the time you get to 7, it is **too late** to influence what happens at step 2.

You could make a new Ajax request to status.php and process the response in JS, but since status.php returns an entire HTML document, that doesn't make sense.

You could use `location` to load a new page using a URL that includes status.php and a query string with information from the Ajax response, but that would making using Ajax in the first place pointless.

You should probably change readDB.php to return *all** the data you need, and then using DOM methods (or jQuery wrappers around them) to modify the page the user is already looking at.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest and fastest (maybe not the sexiest way) to do it :

- create global variable **var respondData;** in **STATUS.PHP**
- within you ajax request on success function assign your data callback to it

`respondData = data;`

Now you have an access to it from every place in your code even when the ajax request is done. Just bare in mind to ensure you will try to access this variable after the page will fully load and after ajax will process the request. Otherwise you will get `'undefined'`